# ASP.NET force file access as pool identity when using windows authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, active-directory

**Introduction:** there is an ASP.NET intranet page that users are accessing with Windows Authentication feature (through Active Directory). Application Pool Identity of this page is set to some domain custom technical account. This intranet page have a feature to access files on some network drive. OS is Windows Server 2019, IIS 10.

**Problem:** Page is accessing files from network drive as current user context, not App Pool Identity. We have made simple test. We created a almost empty page with only one textbox where user can put path to file or directory and button to execute. When pressed, simple if is executed:

```
if (File.Exists(path) || Directory.Exists(path))
```

To check if access to file is possible. Next, we have granted a user an access to file that App Pool Identity does not have. Result should be 'file not found' but File.Exists(path) returned true, as it was invoked from user context.

**Question:** How we can set IIS to access files only from App Pool Identity context?

Answer (score 0):

You could follow below steps to configure iis to use application pool identity:

1)open iis manager.

2)select your site.

3)from the authentication module enable windows authentication adn disable the rest of the authentication.

4)Go back to the site in IIS Manager and open Configuration Editor.

5)For the Section selection, choose “system.webServer/serverRuntime”

6)Select UseWorkerProcessUser

[image]

7)click on apply from the action pane.

you could refer to the below link for more detail:

https://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/iis-using-windows-authentication-with-minimal-permissions-granted-to-disk

Comment: It was a good try, but after that change everything on the page was seen as technical account. I mean users after login saw server account name, not their user names. Anyway, access to files behaved exactly the same as before. I think we will build small local service to access files separately.